# How can I ensure an image is disposed of from method that returns an image

Tags: c#, memory-management, dispose, system.drawing

I have the following code:

```
private Image ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height, bool paddOverflow)
{
    //Calculate sizes here. Removed for brevity

    var target = new Bitmap(image, finalWidth, finalHeight);
    using (var graphic = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        graphic.Clear(Color.White);
        graphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
        graphic.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        graphic.DrawImage(target, 0, 0, finalWidth, finalHeight);

        return target;
    }
}

var image = ResizeImage(someImage, 100, 100, false);
```

The issue I have is that if I wrap `target` in a using statement then `image` won't be valid.

How can I do something like this but ensure that `image` is disposed of. Something feels very off about my approach here but I can't spot it for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure your code doesn't get the images all wrong??? Imo, you should create the Graphics object from the `target` Image. Then you can dispose of `image` before reurning `target`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In situations like this, it's up to the calling code to either dispose of your disposable object correctly or otherwise to leave disposal up to the garbage collector. There's absolutely nothing you can do about this. You cannot wrap the image in your own wrapper class because the same situation would apply -- your wrapper class would either have to have a Dispose method (or something like it) which the calling code would have to call, and/or your wrapper class would have a finalizer which the garbage collector would call.

You should expect that developers using your code are qualified developers who understand disposal and garbage collection.

Comment: Well spoken. I'd like to add something though (since it's not entirely clear in OP's question). The `graphic`-object in your `using`-construct *will* be disposed before returning `target`. *Not* disposing the image is not a huge loss however; it will be garbage-collected eventually. You have to trust your programmers to *know* how to use `Dispose` or `using`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I understand that `graphic` will be disposed, I just wanted to make sure I was doing everything I can elsewhere. If this method is used in a large operation and the target isn't disposed by the developer then I'd imagine memory issues could arise. As long as I'm doing it the best way possible, I'm happy. Thanks again.

Comment: _Not disposing the image is not a huge loss however; it will be garbage-collected eventually._ __No__, It is a `GDI object` and it will __not__ garbage-collected!!

Comment: Image is a managed object around the GDI object. When the managed object is garbage collected, it will properly destroy the GDI object.

Comment: @MichaelGunter: `Image` is an abstract class; what exact resources are wrapped thereby would be up to the implementation.  While many implementations of `Image` might acquire only resources that are fungible and at least somewhat plentiful, others might acquire resources that are non-fungible such as files.  I would consider abandonment appropriate only in cases where one knows the exact type of image one is dealing with and has a good idea of the associated costs.

Comment: Of course. But there are an infinite number of reasons you would write a function that returns a disposable object. OP's API is a perfectly valid case of this. And if you write an API that returns disposable objects, there's nothing you can do from inside your API to ensure clients call your Dispose. That's one of the many reasons garbage collection exists. You assume the developer writing the client code will do his job, and let GC handle the rest.